# Flie zilla not working on PC

Tags: ftp, connection, filezilla

I am using filezilla since 1year. i never had this kind of trouble 
when i work from home i can able to connect filezilla But when i came to office this issue is coming. May i know what could be the possible error or fault..

Suggest Edit if question not reach standards.

[image]

So i can able to use filezilla with my pc the internet connection is different ip is different And

> when i use filezilla from office this error is coming.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. When re-posting there, post a log file for the working connection too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]>

> "Only use plain FTP (insecure)"